# What is the maximum compresion ratio of Deflate64?

Tags: deflate

I would like to know what the max. compression ratio of Deflate64 is.

In the konventional deflate specification the compression ratio is up to 1032:1.

The source of the "1032:1" figure is given on the zlib site where it is told that:

> The limit comes from the fact that one length/distance pair can
>   represent at most 258 output bytes. A length requires at least one bit
>   and a distance requires at least one bit, so two bits in can give 258
>   bytes out, or eight bits in give 1032 bytes out. A dynamic block has
>   no length restriction, so you could get arbitrarily close to the limit
>   of 1032:1.

Since Deflate64 supports lengths up to 65.538 the ratio should be much higher.
Am I right when I simply replace the 258 Bytes in the obve quotation with 65.538 and multiply this with 4 to get a ratio of `262152:1` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  (3 + 65535) * 8 / (16 + 1) = 524304 / 17 ~= 30841.4 : 1.

The base value for the last length code is 3, and the number of extra bits is 15, so the maximum length for a match is 3 + 65535.  You can get that many bytes out, or eight times that in bits, for each length/distance code pair.  524304 bits.  The minimum size for a length code is 1, so with the extra bits, the maximum length can be represented with 16 bits.  That is followed by a distance code for a distance of 1, for which the minimum size is 1 bit.  So we have 17 bits of compressed data to produce 524304 bits of uncompressed data.

Comment: Thank you Mark for the answer. Could you please explain me the components of the calculation? I just multiplied 65538 by 4 but your answer seems to have a lot more information inside. Thanks.

Comment: Good thing you asked.  When I started to explain it, I realized I made a mistake.  That has been corrected.